# If you have to find this type of problem in Angular JS during package installation in Visual Studio Code then follow below steps

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

> PS C:\code\Projects\Exam portal\examfront> **ng add @angular/material**

```
see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng add @angular/material
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Title should identify what the problem is. Question should expand on that. Currently both are unclear. Also question is tagged angularjs which is for obsolete versions 1.XX, not the more current [tag:angular]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:>  PS C:\code\Projects\Exam portal\examfront> **set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -S**

Step 2:>  PS C:\code\Projects\Exam portal\examfront> **Get-ExecutionPolicy**

RemoteSigned

Scope ExecutionPolicy

```
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Step 3:>  PS C:\code\Projects\Exam portal\examfront> **ng --version**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 12.0.3
Node: 14.15.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.9
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.3
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.3
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.3
@schematics/angular             12.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

Step 4:>  PS C:\code\Projects\Exam portal\examfront> **ng add @angular/material**

```
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/material@12.0.3.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/material@12.0.3 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Package successfully installed.
? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Indigo/Pink   ngular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes
? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes
UPDATE package.json (1137 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (502 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (3260 bytes)
UPDATE src/index.html (577 bytes)
UPDATE src/styles.css (181 bytes)
```